# Storyboard.RepeatBehavior Ineffective

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I have a program where I have added a button to toggle weather or not a storyboard I am using should repeat

```
private void Repeat_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (globalStoryboard.Children.Count != 0)
  {
    if (globalStoryboard.RepeatBehavior == RepeatBehavior.Forever)
      globalStoryboard.RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(1.0);
    else
      globalStoryboard.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
  }
}
```

But it isn't working at all. When the animation reaches the end of the first play the Completed event fires(It shouldn't do that) and the animation just stops(That either). I've tried a couple different approaches to no avail and all my searching seems to indicate it's an isolated problem.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here's one of the places where I add some animations to a storyboard. The function this is chopped out of returns the Storyboard s which I then make a child of GlobalStoryboard. I already tried passing GlobalStoryboard to the function and adding the animations directly to it to remove the intermediary storyboard. It did not fix the problem.

```
double last = ((data[0] - min) / delta) * angle;
for (double k = 1.001; k < data.Count; k++)
{
  double val = ((data[(int)k] - min) / delta) * angle;
  DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
  doubleAnimation.From = last;
  doubleAnimation.To = val;
  doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
  doubleAnimation.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(k - 1);
  s.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
  Storyboard.SetTargetName(doubleAnimation, "AxisRotation" + index);
  Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath("Angle"));
  last = val;
}
```

Comment: why don´t you just stop the storyboard, if you want it to exit?

Comment: I guess this is because Storyboard is frozen after beginning. Probably you have to replace it.

Comment: Create a new storyboard every time the user toggles the repeat behavior? Yikes, not the solution I was hoping for.

Comment: I'm confused. so the code snippet you have fires on Completed, or on Button Press? If so, it looks like you turn off repeat behavior when the animation completes its first time, which would explain why the animation stops.  

I'd love to see more of your code. Most likely your animation isn't tied to the storyboard properly. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/wpf/thread/fdf468c8-0780-4a17-a4dd-1910589c2171

Comment: I've reworded the question to make it more clear, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LPL was correct, when a storyboard is animating it is frozen to prevent interference. I just made the repeat button bind to a Boolean and made the completed event play the storyboard again if it was true.